# Excel VBA - Type mismatch on Find function

Tags: excel, vba, find, goto, type-mismatch

Having a little trouble with a Find function.
I have an excel sheet where column A is showing weekdays and column B has the date.
I'm trying to auto-scroll to today's date but to the start of the respective week (monday) if "today" is not monday. For that, I used offset to search up to 6 days before today's date.
Although I get a Type Mismatch error on the second Find funtion that is searching for the closest previous monday in column A.

Do you have any idea why could this be happening?

My current code is as below:

```
Sub Go_to_Today_Button()

Dim searchResult As range
Dim today As range
Dim currentWeek As range
Dim previousMonday As range
   
Set searchResult = Cells.Find(What:=Date, After:=range("B3"), LookIn:=xlFormulas _
        , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

Set today = searchResult.Offset(0, -1)
Set currentWeek = searchResult.Offset(-6, -1)
Set previousMonday = Nothing
   
previousMonday = Cells.Find("Monday", range(currentWeek.Address(), today.Address()), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

Application.Goto Reference:=range(previousMonday), Scroll:=True

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: [*Note that `After` must be a single cell in the range*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find#parameters)

Comment: You forgot to use the keyword `Set` to assign the range to `previousMonday`.

Comment: Thank you for your replies!
Although, none of the changes suggested fixed the issue.
Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Are you sure you really have "Monday" as text in the weekday column? If this were my workbook I would use the available date from the other column and display it as "dddd". That would make the values in the two columns the same, and give you a date to look for, not "Monday". Check the cell formats in both columns.

Comment: Thanks, Variatus! Yes, I have "Monday" as text in the weekday column. I tried having both columns with the same values (column A with "dddd" showing the weekdays). However I would still need to have the Find function searching for a 2 (for example, with sunday being 1). and the same type mismatch error pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the previous Monday and just search for that.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Go_to_Today_Button()

    Dim previousMonday As Date
    previousMonday = Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 1

    Dim ws As Worksheet, iLastRow As Long
    Dim rngSearch As Range, rngFound As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngSearch = ws.Range("B3:B" & iLastRow)
       
    Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=previousMonday, After:=Range("B3"), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto Reference:=rngFound, Scroll:=True
    Else
        MsgBox "Could not find " & previousMonday
    End If
End Sub
```